# What's wrong with using static for Parent Activities?

Tags: java, android, static

Let's say I have a parent activity ParentHost with a *static* reference:

```
   ParentHost extends FragmentActivity {
   static ParentHost parent_host;
   static ViewPager pager;
```

**Now let's use a reference like:**

```
public class TestPage extends Fragment {   
            button.setOnClickListener(new  View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    //What's wrong with this?
                    ParentHost.pager.setCurrentItem(1);
                    or:
                    ParentHost.parent_host.finish();
                }
            });
```

I've tried breaking my app (start,pause,killed RAM) and I haven't seen any issues.

Is this method ok for parent activities?

**For future readers:**

Switching to `((ParentHost) getActivity()).whatever()`, is the appropriate way of using an instance of a running class. From Gabe's comment:

> The reason its safe is its held in an instance variable and not in a
>   static. Thus even though there's always 1 reference to it the GC can
>   tell that the only reference to it is held by one of its children and
>   that the whole chain can be GCed (the ability to do this is why java
>   uses a mark and sweep style GC instead of a reference count)

Comment: When the activity isn't open it still can't be garbage collected. (because a static field is referring to it)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well you don't need it.  A fragment can get its activity by calling getActivity().

In addition, its a memory leak.  If a Fragment has a static reference to its activity, that Activity will never be cleaned.  Which means any object it holds will never be cleaned.  Which means all of its views, bitmaps, and memory structures, which will just kill your RAM.

So its a pretty bad idea, and gives you no benefit.  Why would you want to do it?

Comment: What if you do a: .finish() on that static reference? Does that static reference get GC'd?

Comment: No.  Finish doesn't cause garbage collection, it just puts the object in a state where its no longer valid as a context.  As long as there's a reference to it it may not be garbage collected.

Comment: Oh ok that's what I wanted to know, could you add that to your answer so I can mark it? Thanks!

Comment: Also, is ((ParentHost) getActivity()).whatever() from @Alireza's comment safe?

Comment: getActivity is safe.  The reason its safe is its held in an instance variable and not in a static.  Thus even though there's always 1 reference to it the GC can tell that the only reference to it is held by one of its children and that the whole chain can be GCed (the ability to do this is why java uses a mark and sweep style GC instead of a reference count).

Comment: Ah ok, could you add all of of this to your answer, it's been really helpful and may help future readers!

Answer (score 2):

What's wrong?

Well, let's just say that you closed this activity. Now any instance level field (*non-static* field) will go out of scope and be garbage collected.

But in case of *static* fields, the instances linger around and will be present until the class gets GCed (which happens when the classloader gets GCed). So, using static for widgets o objects which occupy lot of memory is *not advised*.

Comment: So the static reference to ViewPager pager; would not just be reused and assigned to a new one if we opened the activity again?

Comment: What if you do a: .finish() on that static reference? Does that get GC'd?

Comment: @Petro - No. finishing an activity and unloading the class loader are 2 different things

Comment: @Petro Think about `finish()` as saying to Android, "Close this activity and I'm finished with it.  Do whatever you want to it".  The whatever you want is to free it for garbage collection but as others have pointed out, a static reference will prevent the activity from being GCed until the class is unloaded.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need static reference at all. do this

```
((ParentHost) getActivity()).whatever()
```